# Difficulty aligning form elements to look correct and be responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having difficulty aligning my form elements to look something like this:

[image]

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix it, I've been trying with the CSS so far but nothing seems to be working. Furthermore, it doesn't seem to be responsive, when I scale down the browser window there is a lot of overflow. This is my code so far:

**CSS**

```
.bookings {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.bookings h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F3C;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: blue;
}
.bookingform input, .bookingform textarea, .bookingform select {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.bookingform {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 2em;
}
.bookingform textarea {
    width: 30%;
    height: 60%;
}
.option label {
    display: block;
    width: 20em;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 20em;
}
input#time {
    display: inline;
}
.bookingform input type=["checkbox"] {
 float:right;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zqqb62j8/1/

Comment: Make all labels inline blocks and set them the same width and text align left

Comment: @MartinMalinda - Hi Martin, can you please show me an example on the jsfiddle i posted many thanks

Comment: The question lacks a clear problem statement and HTML code, and in the jsfiddle, the CSS code is really not related to the HTML code in it. You should not expect others to write code for you to implement a visual design given as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Reduced the width and the right margin of labels, and set them to inline-blocks. Also, removed inputs from them, they don't need to be label's children, but siblings:

```
.option label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
```

See what it looks like for the first three elements: http://jsfiddle.net/zqqb62j8/2/

---

UPDATE

Here's a more simple/readable example, similar to what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/zqqb62j8/7/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the first part of your html and replaced the css. Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqqb62j8/5/). I gave all labels, input and textareas a width so they end lined up nicely. Further I used basic floating and clearing to position everything.

```
.option{
    background-color: #DDD;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
.option label{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.option input, .option textarea{
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
h1{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very usual problem, I would recommend you to do it the hard way and keep only the necessary formatting as mentioned above but what I want to mention is you can do it quick by using some tools that allow you align elements using GUI,

Online Tools:
You can align and see how it works using following tools that you can run in your browser:

-http://www.cssdesk.com/

-http://jsfiddle.net/

Softwares with WYSIWYG:
WYSIWYG (/ˈwɪziwɪɡ/ WIZ-ee-wig) is an acronym for "What You See Is What You Get".

-Dreamweaver: One of the best tools for the web designing that I use.
Tutorial on aligning elements using Dreamweaver: [youtube.com/watch?v=eG5rkN80hSI](http://youtube.com/watch?v=eG5rkN80hSI)

-Amaya: Built for windows/linix/mac

Further, although what you ask is very specific I just wanted to list out better way to do it. Hope it helps.